# AngularJS loading REST API service

Tags: angularjs

In my app I need an API REST connection with server so I've decided to use this one: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular but when I try to load it into my module:

```
var app = angular.module('onboarding',['ngRoute','ngSanitize','ngStorage','restangular']);
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to instantiate module restangular due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/nomod?p0=rest...
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:6:425
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:25:399
at b (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:24:439)
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:25:173
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:41:117
at q (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:7:351)
at g (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:40:476)
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:41:134
at q (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:7:351)
at g (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:40:476
```

In documentation on github it is written that only versions between 1.0.X and 1.5.X are supported. Since I use version 1.6.2 that could be the problem. But when I've changed my version to 1.5.9 again I get exactly the same error.

Is that bug with my code or with this library?  Has anyone had similar error with angular version coincidence?

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet. And please make sure that you have added the required js file for restangular. Also, do include it as a dependency in the main module.

Comment: Sure! I've edidted my code.

Comment: restangular should work fine in 1.6.2;  as to the error you are getting, that usually happens when your scripts aren't included in the HTML or they are in the wrong order.  you can use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` to get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: I've included each file into my HTML code (no errors about that). This is my order of scripts: 1. jQuery 2. jQuery-UI 3.Boostrap 4.Angular 5.ngRoute 6.restangular 7.ngStorage 8. angular-sanitize

Comment: Now I've found something strange:  after loading restangular module on my command console I get error from : jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 not from restangular. What jQuery has to do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the cause: That `Restangular` depends on `angular`, `angular-resource` and `underscore`. If you don't have [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) in your references, add it and test it once more.

This is not explicitly mentioned in their documentation. You can also use [Lodash](https://lodash.com) for this purpose.

Comment: Yes. Now it works properly. My bad. Thank you for solving my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Either `restangular` is not installed in your project or you haven't imported `restangular`.

Did you import them in your index page ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.5.1/restangular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.5.1/restangular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I did. Also now I see that this error come from jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2. So maybe there is a problem with coincidence between jQuery and restangular?